# Issue about the zip file path in Python Script

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation

I'm using the following code snippet, to zip the file from a particular directory, however, when I unzip the file at targetPath, it creates another folder path with the following structure:

> */u01/backup/u01/data/abc/xyz/logs.*

What changes can be done in the script to make a folder path as:

> */u01/backup/logs*

, when I unzip it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import zipfile
import datetime
def zipdir(path, ziph):
    # ziph is zipfile handle
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            ziph.write(os.path.join(root, file))
Time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
sourcePath = '/u01/data/abc/xyz/logs'
targetPath = '/u01/backup/'
fname = targetPath + 'backup-'+ str(Time)+'.zip'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(fname, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    zipdir(sourcePath, zipf)
    zipf.close()
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an overloadded function of `ZipFile.write` to specifiy the name inside the zip:

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write :

> ZipFile.write(filename, **arcname**=None, compress_type=None,
>   compresslevel=None)
>
> Write the file named filename to the archive, giving it the archive
>   name **arcname** (by default, this will be the same as filename, but
>   without a drive letter and with leading path separators removed).  [...]

So

```
 ziph.write(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.join('/u01/backup/logs',file) )
```

should put your files into better suited folder inside the zip - if you want to preserve part of the original path you need to provide that part as second parameter to write.

You can use os.path.split / join to mangle file names - see https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html